# How to find a div with part of a class name and get remaining part of that class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

There are several divs on my page with classes `my_widget-2`, `my_widget-8`, etc. 
What JavaScript or jQuery code can I use to get the number "2" (ie. the number that appends the *first* matching widget)?

Note: If I were to write this question again, I would change the order of these class names and ask for a way to get "8" in order to avoid giving the impression that I want the smaller number.

Comment: Please clarify if you have only one or multiple classes so I can edit my answer to show you how to retrieve the number part.

Comment: Yes, the divs have other classes (eg. 'widget', 'my_widget')

Comment: I think you should clarify what exactly you want to have. Is it all DIV elements with the class `my_widget-2` (since you wrote “get the number 2”) or do you want to have all DIV elements with a class of the form `my_widget-N`?

Comment: I want to get the number "2" only. Just the number.
Next, I will use the number to style another div's background image.

Comment: Responses so far could have been useful for a bigger number of users as they don't answer a too specific need like mine. And they will be lost when (if) you make changes to your codes :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$( "[class*='my_widget']" ).each ( function () {
    var elClasses = $( this ).attr ( 'class' ).split ( ' ' );

    for ( var index in elClasses ) {
        if ( elClasses[index].match ( /^my_widget-\d+$/ ) ) {
            var classNum = elClasses[index].split ( '-' )[1];
            alert ( classNum );
            break;
        }
    }
} );
```

Use the "[attributeContains](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeContains#attributevalue)" selector to get all elements that have a class `my_widget-*`, and then loop trough all the classes the element has searching for you class. Once you find it, extract the number part.

Comment: What if the element has multple classes? The startswith wouldn't work for them.

Comment: Make it "[class*='my_widget']" and it should work in the case of multiple classes.

Comment: @ryanulit: hehe, was adding that, didn't see your comment :)

Comment: What about class names just containing `my_widget` like `not_my_widget`?

Comment: It now only matches classes in the form "my_widget-NUM"

Comment: @Jan Hančič: No, it doesn’t. It will also match `not_my_widget-N` and `my_widget-N-foobar`. :-)

Comment: This is almost there. I am getting two results: 2 and 8 as a result of this. How can I get only the first one ("2")?

If left to me, I will try to insert a loop and a counter but I am pretty sure you jQuery experts know a better way.

Comment: I figured it out by using `:first`. It is fine for the answer to stay as it is, so more people can make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$("[class^='my_widget']").each(function() {
    var classParts = $(this).attr('class').split('-');
    var number = classParts.pop();
});
```

Please note that it will only work if there is a singular class, otherwise you'd get something like `8 otherclass` as a result.

Comment: Another tricky part here is that I only want the first number suffix ('2'), not the others... not actually sure if jQuery is the right tool to approach this.

This whole thing really is part of a Wordpress situation but I wasn't able to add my original question that had a link to this one. (noob -> need to wait another 10 mins. or so)

Answer (score 1):

Basic JS approach:

```
<div id="x" class="widget-2 lang-日本語">foo</div>

function Element_getClassArgument(el, name) {
    var classes= el.className.split(' ');
    var prefix= name+'-';
    for (var i= classes.length; i-->0;)
        if (classes[i].substring(0, prefix.length)==prefix)
            return classes[i].substring(prefix.length);
    return null;
}

Element_getClassArgument(document.getElementById('x'), 'widget'); // 2
```

If you wanted to include whitespace characters, or a hyphen in a name, you'd have to introduce an encoding scheme of some sort, for example `encodeURIComponent`. But often you can get away without that.

Wrapping in something with `$` in the name is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the DIV elements with a class `my_widget-2`, use this selector:

```
$("div.my_widget-2")
```

But if you want to get all DIV elements with a class of the form `my_widget-N` where *N* is an arbitrary number, try this:

```
$("div[class]").each(function() {
    var matches = this.className.match(/(?:^|\s+)my_widget-(\d+)(?:\s+|$)/g);
    if (matches !== null) {
        alert(matches);
    }
})
```

Comment: I downvoted your original answer that didn't make any sense. Now I can't undo :\

Comment: @Jan Hančič: And why didn’t it make any sense? He just asked how to get the “number 2” of some DIV elements with classes like `my_widget-2` and `my_widget-8`. If “number 2” refers to the DIV elements with the class `my_widget-2` my previous answer makes perfect sense.

Comment: No, he wants to get elements that have a class like my_widget-AND SOME NUMBER. And originally you had the wrong selector even for that what you are saying :)

Comment: @Jan Hančič: And where did he say that?

Comment: I think it's clear from his question. Why would he need to get "2" if he already knew the full class name "my_widget-2"?

Comment: I neutralized the downvote. Jan: you can remove the downvote if Gumbo has edited the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`element.attr('class').match(/my_widget-(\d+)/)[1]`

It should return the column number as a string so just run parseInt() on it