# How to get element class by prefix via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to get an element class by prefix?

For example I have:

```
<div class="cc-colour-red cc-size-big cc-width-narrow">
```

How to get those separately - the colour, te size and the width?

I hope that makes sense.

I have the DOM element selected. The final result would be "big", "red" and "narrow".

Thanks!

Comment: The best way would be to not use classes for this. Use individual `data-*` attributes for each property instead. Are you able to change the HTML format?

Comment: I know, but this is not possible in that particular case.

Comment: What do you want? The values of CSS `color`, `font-size` and `width`?

Comment: if i understood it correctly, please see my answer.

Comment: I want to get "big", "red" and "narrow"

Comment: Please check the data attribute, i think will better used than classes https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: This question is probably for learning-only intended. I love it!

Comment: @Spiro I added an answer for you which works on the classes you have on the elements, but using `data` attributes would still be a better approach by far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/c1d9fuwr/3/):

JavaScript

```
$("div").each(function(index, elem){
  var classes = $(elem).attr("class");
  var color = classes.replace(/.*cc-colour-([^\s]+).*/g, "$1");
  var size = classes.replace(/.*cc-size-([^\s]+).*/g, "$1");
  var width = classes.replace(/.*cc-width-([^\s]+).*/g, "$1");
  console.log(color, size, width); //red big narrow, blue small wide, green medium narrow
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="cc-colour-red cc-size-big cc-width-narrow">
<div class="cc-colour-blue cc-size-small cc-width-wide">
<div class="cc-colour-green cc-size-medium cc-width-narrow">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get DOM element by class prefix, you can use this selector:

```
^=
```

If you are using multiple css classes, there is another selector for 'contains':

```
*=
```

Example:

```
$("[class^='cc-size-']")
```

Comment: This is half an answer at best. How do you get the key/values from the classes?

Comment: I should clarify. I have the DOM element selected, I want to get those values "big", "red" by prefixes "colour", "width" etc from element's classes.

Comment: Ok, got it. Look at @RoryMcCrossan answer, I think it's best one

Comment: Look at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006290) I think that's exactly what you want

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.querySelector()`, with selector `"[class|=cc]"`, `.className`, `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/cc-|\s/g` to exclude prefix from replacement string. You could alternatively use `.match()` to return an array of values

```js
var values = document.querySelector("[class|=cc]")
             .className.replace(/cc-|\s/g," ");
console.log(values);
```

```html
<div class="cc-colour-red cc-size-big cc-width-narrow">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this would be to not use classes at all, and instead use individual `data-*` attributes for each property.

If you cannot change the HTML then you could achieve what you required by creating an array of objects which contains the key/value pairs. You can then use the index of the element to relate it to the key/value pairs object:

```
var arr = $('div').map(function() {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < this.classList.length; i++) {
        var className = this.classList[i];
        var matches = /^cc-(.+)-(.+)$/.exec(className);
        obj[matches[1]] = matches[2];
    }
    return obj;
}).get();
```

Example output:

```
[{
    "colour": "red",
    "size": "big",
    "width": "narrow"
}]
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/p7L8vsmp/1/)

This approach has the benefit of being completely extensible; if you add any other classes then the code will automatically work without changes.

Comment: The `div` in OP does not have any `id`, won't that be a problem?

Comment: Nice workaround, but i'd strongly suggest using data values, too

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I agree, as I mentioned in the first paragraph. I can only assume that the OP is being provided the HTML from an external source, or is using this as a learning excercise.

Comment: @Arg0n possibly, although you could just as well use the elements index and put it in an array. I used an object in this case to make the example clearer, and association easier.

Comment: Well, the statement "If you cannot change the HTML ..." kindof contradicts the answer.

Comment: @Arg0n very true, an oversight by me. I added an array implementation that avoids the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
$("div").prop("classList").forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry.split('-')[2]);
});
```

Comment: the first description led to sth like this. now, in comments, he explained it in more detail.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I believe it makes more sense now in the first post.